# Wordpress Section headings as thumbnails

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have this page here: http://new.leicesterymca.co.uk/youth-community/our-work/ Im trying to create a thumbnail menu for it, as per the image attached.

The green menu on the left hand side comes from a widget and displays a list of 3rd level pages, but instead of them being in a list the left, I would like to have the the li items displayed as rows of 3 or 4 images.

I imagine I can do this with CSS and apply a block of colour or the same background image for each li item for example, but I would perhaps like to display the header image of the target page. so the client has control over it.

The menu displays as a standard ul with li Items...

```
<ul>
  <li>Menu Item one</li>
  <li>Menu Item two</li>
  <li>Menu Item three</li>
  <li>Menu Item four</li>
  <li>Menu Item five</li>
</ul>
```

But I'm looking to perhaps assign a background image to each li element. The background image will come from the target page of the li element.

I hope that's clearer.

Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I understand that, but I don't really have any code I'm trying to fix, I'm trying to find a solution to a problem I believe to be quite specific, rather than just saying 'my website isn't working, help'... I could post some general <li> elements I guess and ask how to pull through the featured image from a target page? - Ill do that :)